# Unable to load dll

Tags: c#, dll, path, dllimport

I am trying to load a dll using DllImport, it works fine if I specified the path of the dll, however, if I do not specified the path of the dll, and just type "foo.dll", it complains "Unable to load dll" even thou I have put the dll file into the bin folder already.

I thought if I do not specified the dll path, it will assume that it will start the dll in the same folder as the exe file, but it seems like it is not the case.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I have put the dll file into the bin folder"? Do you mean `bin/Debug`? Are you running in debug mode from Visual Studio?

Comment: @PlayKid, that might be a dependency problem. You can use a tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check if everything gets correctly resolved.

Comment: Webste or normal application= the fules are different. What language? Come one, give us baseline information here. We dont see over your shoulder.

Comment: Hi Mark, you are right, bin/Debug or bin/Release, I have that dll in both.

Comment: Hi TomTom, it's C# in Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi Frederic, It seems like it is something to do with the Dependency....but now, my question would be I cannot specify the exact path of the dll as it can change, I tried to put the path to the app.config, but DllImport do not like that as it is not a const variable.

Comment: @PlayKid, from your comment to Wiktor's answer it looks like your DLL depends at least on `load4cxx.dll`. You can either copy all such dependencies with the DLL in your `bin` folder, or make sure they reside in a folder that's listed in your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the DLL you are trying to load depends on other resources. You can trick the `DllImport` by first calling the Win32's `LoadLibrary` on the remote path. `DllImport` will notice that the library has already been loaded into memory and it should just work.

The code snippet:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("yourlibrary.dll")]
    public static extern void Foo();

    public void CallTheFooMethod()
    {
       // first load the library
       LoadLibrary( "C:/..........full path/yourlibrary.dll" );

       Foo();  
    }
```

Comment: "The program can't start because log4cxx.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

Comment: Easy to fix. It seems that your native library uses the log4cxx as the logging subsystem. Try to copy the library beside your native library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320671/3195477

Answer (score 0):

In your C++ dll project open the project properties, navigate to C/C++ -> Code Generation. Then for runtime library set Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) for Debug configuration and Multi-threaded (/MT) for Release. After that you may put compiled dll in your output directory and check if that works. Feel free to comment and ask questions.

**UPD:**

Here is the [link to the simple little project](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?g9y4nehzgk9wasc), which measures current CPU frequency using native code, DllImport'ed to the C# project code.

Steps to build:
1. Build C++ project in any configuration (actually it is not important what configuration to use in this sample).
2. Find compiled dll in the configuration output folder (Debug|Release)
3. Add found dll to the ExternalLibraries folder in the C# project, set action to Copy If Newest in the file Properties (right click on a lib -> Properties).
4. Build and Run C# project -> profit.

Why I suggested this to you: my client asked for a code which will measure CPU frequency, I've ran this code just fine on my machine, but the client didn't. It was dependent on MS VC runtime libs. After setting Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) for Debug configuration and Multi-threaded (/MT) for Release code of all dependencies becomes embedded in your binary, therefore at least one source of dependencies you can resolve already.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for your project, however, it seems like it is dependency issue, I cannot just load the dll, but to load the dll inside its installed folder to make sure all the dependecies are loaded as well. So now I need some sort of mechanism to assign the path either at run time or at a config file, but I am having challenges.

Comment: Is it your own dll or third-party? Could you please provide a link or project with that dll?

Answer (score -1):

If you dont want to use a path you could always place the dll in the Windows GAC ([wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)). It can be a pain to do as sometimes you need to sign your dll but means in can be accessed without the path.

Comment: You can't add native *.dlls to the GAC.

Comment: @WiktorZychla if by native dlls you mean ones created by a user (not my microsoft) you can. this is how you used to create webparts for sharepoint - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx

Comment: Nope. A "native dll" is a win32 one. Only these are loaded by DllImport.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Sorry was looking at native from a diffetent perspective, i.e native to application etc. My fault :). Native dlls are stored in system32 folder which don't need a path (if I remember correctly) so the OP can't be talking about a native dll, it must be user made (or 3rd party made) which in that case adding to the GAC is viable.

Comment: Nope again :) Native DLLs can easily be coded in C/C++ and can be stored anywhere in your OS. You load them with `LoadLibrary` and this is the way .NET PInvoke uses them. You can't store them in GAC.