# Unable to load DLL in C#

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

**how to load a dll in a c# project**

**error**:

> Unable to load DLL 'Reader.dll': The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

**code sample**:

```
[DllImport("Reader.dll")]
 public static extern byte OpenReader(ref IntPtr hCom, byte LinkType, string com_port);
```

image:
[image: exception screenshot]

Comment: Probably obvious question, but the dll is of course actually present?

Comment: yes it's present. in fact if try to add a reference and i choose the dll as a target. i face this error: a reference to c:\...\reader.dll could no be added

Comment: You can't add a reference to the dll because it is not a .NET assembly. It has nothing to do with your issue.
Try using dependency Walker to debug your issue http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Is the reader.dll a c/c++ library? Does it have any dependencies itself that perhaps it cannot find? Is it a com library that can be registered and if so does it register?

Comment: the dEpendency walker tool shows two missing dll files: GPSVC.dll and IESHIMS.DLL

Comment: Based on the names for the missing dlls, it looks like this reader dll might be for reading gps data. If this is a pc, do you have the gps harware along with its drivers installed? Perhaps there is an sdk that you have not installed.

Comment: @Alex GPSVC = Group Policy Service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Although the reader.dll is unable to load GPSVC.dll and IESHIMS.DLL. 
i managed to make it work by running the corflags command on application.exe
the application is now marked as 32bit**:

---

```
corflags application.exe /32bit+
```

---

Version   : v4.0.30319

CLR Header: 2.5

PE        : PE32

CorFlags  : 3

ILONLY    : 1

**32BIT     : 1**

Signed    : 0

Answer (score 13):

If the problem is really "cannot be found", then using ProcMon from Sysinternals will show you where the system is looking for the DLL.

However, often these sort of exceptions mean 'I found the DLL but I can't load it', and that can be because a dependency of the DLL is missing rather than the DLL itself, or because the DLL is incompatible with the app trying to load it.  If your C# app is set for 'Any CPU' and you're on a 64bit machine, you'll get this sort of error loading unmanaged 32-bit DLLs.

One way to isolate the problem would be to create a simple C/C++ project which loads the DLL. (Load it dynamically with LoadLibrary if you don't have access to the import lib.) Then use Dependency Walker to profile the test harness, and it will report the names of missing DLLs.

Comment: THank you @Will I am on a 64bit machine, debug is set for 'x86'. it a visual c++ 6.0 DLL and running the dependency walker showed 2 missing dll :GPSVC.dll and IESHIMS.DLL. any ideas?

Comment: @john did you ever get this resolved? I'm running into the same thing and could use some more ideas for debugging this. Thx! (GPSVC.dll and IESHIMS.DLL)

Comment: @M3NTA7 please check my accepted answer. GPSVC.dll and IESHIMS.DLL weren't the problem. in my case it was a x64/x86 issue.
as ideas: check if your dll is in the debug folder. compile your project as x86(maybe you don't need to use coreflags, running as x86 will do the job ).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple C DLL it just needs to be in the same folder as the .exe.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in another post. Maybe it will help your situation

[NUnit "missing" GPSVC.DLL on Windows 7/64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877098/nunit-missing-gpsvc-dll-on-windows-7-64)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to installing the C++ Redistrable X64 on client machine.
(Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019.)

The dll was already on the right place, in the same folder than the .exe file.

Here you found the download link:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0